# Docker create network on WSL

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using windows WSL. Have started a docker on windows and exposed the port for WSL using option `Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS`

in `.bashrc`

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375
```

My all other docker commands are working fine. But when I try to create a network it fails

```
sudo docker network create mynetwork
```

with error

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Answer (score 0):

During installing of docker etc. I followed a tutorial which gives sudo access for docker.

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

so sudoing again is not working. Without sudo the command is working good.

```
docker network create mynetwork
```